# Struggling with Moq: The following setups were not matched

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq for the first time, and I'm struggling with getting the tests to run properly.

I'm trying to moq the `Save()` method of my service layer.

```
public void Save(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
    // todo: this still doesn't address updating a password. The UserViewModel doesn't contain any Password data.
    if (viewModel.Id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        // The UserId is not empty, we're either updating an existing user
        // or we're inserting a new user via sync
        var user = _userRepository.GetById(viewModel.Id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // Looks like we're updating a user because they're already in the database.
            _userRepository.Update(_userViewModelToModelMapper.BuildFrom(viewModel));
            return;
        }
    }

    // The user is being created, either via a Sync (Guid Exists), or via an Insert (Guid doesn't Exist)
    _userRepository.Create(_userViewModelToModelMapper.BuildFrom(viewModel));
}
```

I've got Three tests, of which, ***I'm not sure any of them are right***. The first two are passing, but the third one fails with

> Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched:
>   IUserRepository r => r.Update(It.Is(um => um.Equals()))

Here are the tests.

```
// PASSES but could be suspect
[Test]
public void ShouldSaveANewUserFromExistingId()
{
    // emulating a "sync"

    // Setup
    var userId = new Guid("81C7FE19-2DB5-4083-BD6A-5433687561F7");
    var userModel = new UserModel();
    var userViewModel = new UserViewModel {Id = userId};
    var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var viewModelToModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserViewModel, UserModel>>();
    var modelToViewModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserModel, UserViewModel>>();

    // Setup the Mock UserRepository
    userRepository.Setup(r => r.Create(It.Is<UserModel>(um => um.Equals(userModel))));

    viewModelToModelMapper.Setup(vmm => vmm.BuildFrom(It.Is<UserViewModel>(u => u.Equals(userViewModel))))
           .Returns(userModel);

    var userService = new UserService(userRepository.Object, viewModelToModelMapper.Object, modelToViewModelMapper.Object);

    // Execute
    userService.Save(userViewModel);

    // Assert
    userRepository.VerifyAll();
    viewModelToModelMapper.VerifyAll();
}
```

```
// PASSES but could be suspect.
[Test]
public void ShouldSaveANewUser()
{
    // emulating a standard create

    // Setup
    var userId = Guid.Empty;
    var userModel = new UserModel();
    var userViewModel = new UserViewModel { Id = userId };
    var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var viewModelToModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserViewModel, UserModel>>();
    var modelToViewModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserModel, UserViewModel>>();

    // Setup the Mock UserRepository
    userRepository.Setup(r => r.Create(It.Is<UserModel>(um => um.Equals(userModel))));

    viewModelToModelMapper.Setup(vmm => vmm.BuildFrom(It.Is<UserViewModel>(u => u.Equals(userViewModel))))
           .Returns(userModel);

    var userService = new UserService(userRepository.Object, viewModelToModelMapper.Object, modelToViewModelMapper.Object);

    // Execute
    userService.Save(userViewModel);

    // Assert
    userRepository.VerifyAll();
    viewModelToModelMapper.VerifyAll();

}
```

```
// FAILS MISERABLY
[Test]
public void ShouldSaveAnExistingUser()
{
    // emulating an "Update"

    // Setup
    var userId = new Guid("0A88AEC2-9F8D-44DE-BD01-3EB9A23C78E3");
    var userModel = new UserModel { Id = userId };
    var userViewModel = new UserViewModel { Id = userId };
    var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var viewModelToModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserViewModel, UserModel>>();
    var modelToViewModelMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper<UserModel, UserViewModel>>();

    // Setup the Mock UserRepository
    userRepository.Setup(r => r.Update(It.Is<UserModel>(um => um.Equals(userModel))));

    viewModelToModelMapper.Setup(vmm => vmm.BuildFrom(It.Is<UserViewModel>(u => u.Equals(userViewModel))))
           .Returns(userModel);

    var userService = new UserService(userRepository.Object, viewModelToModelMapper.Object, modelToViewModelMapper.Object);

    // Execute
    userService.Save(userViewModel);

    // Assert
    userRepository.VerifyAll();
    viewModelToModelMapper.VerifyAll();
}
```

Where am I going wrong with my Moqing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like in the last case you would need:

```
userRepository.Setup(r => r.GetById(userId)).Returns(userModel);
```

Before the userService.Save call.  Without it userRepository.GetById will always be null and the update branch will never be taken.

Comment: I'm not trying to GetById, I'm trying to "Update"

Comment: Yes, but the update will only be called if the GetById method returns a non-null value. Since you haven't set up the GetById method on the repository mock it will return a default value, which for reference types is null. The if statement in the user service then evaluates to false and the update doesn't get called.